# Flexslider 2 direction nav pointers missing from download

Tags: image, flexslider, missing-data

Where can I get Flexslider2's image file for the direction nav pointers: bg_direction_nav.png?

Couldn't work out why I kept getting strange text like 'Fl' or 'Fi' in place of the arrows on the slider.
Checking through everything, I have found that the background image and the css pointing to it are missing from the download package!

Could the missing image be my missing link and can I adapt the css?
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 16):

You need to set the 4 **flexslider-icon** files in a fonts subfolder, besides in the **flexslider.css** change this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'flexslider-icon';
src:url('../fonts/flexslider-icon.eot');
src:url('../fonts/flexslider-icon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/flexslider-icon.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/flexslider-icon.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/flexslider-icon.svg#flexslider-icon') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal}
```

The "**..**" are crucial in the beginning of the fonts path.

Answer (score 6):

**Hi!
You are missing the "flexslider-icon.eot" , "flexslider-icon" and "flexslider-icon.woff".

Probably you are looking for the files inside the demo folder, but they are not there.

Download and unzip the Flex Slider,  then you can see 3 folders, the files must be in 
"C:\Users\YourPCName\Desktop\woothemes-FlexSlider-ca347d4\fonts"

Then change the source for the font-face in the CSS and you' re done!**